# How do I connect to Neo4j using URL?

Tags: neo4j, installation

Earlier version of Neo4j required you to connect database which was stored in your computer .
Recent version asks for some URL instead. Can someone help me with the URL?

[image]

Comment: This would be the url for bolt ex. bolt//localhost:7687 so dbms connection url